# Which query will be faster

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am having a user table with 17 fields and a user details table with 40 fields and both are connected using user_id which is primary key of user table.they are not cascaded
Both these tables will be having rows up to 400,000 to 500,000
In my software most of the time i will be needing to join these two tables for producing outputs.

My question is, will my query run faster if i remove the user details table and put its fields in user table itself.so that i can get results with out using join queries

Which one is better 
1) all fields in one table OR
2) two tables and using join queries

Comment: What database technology are you using?

Comment: Whats a typeical query size? i.e few users or 100,000 users. Do you retrieve all the fields of just a few?

Comment: MySQL with MyISAM, the user table keeps on increasing day by day and can reach upto 400,000 to 500,000 in span of one year.initailly it consists of above 900 users

Answer (score 6):

I'm not trying to be a smartass, but the only reasonable answer is "try it and measure for yourself".

You see, there are too many unknown variables in your question:

- tables' engine(s) (MyISAM, InnoDB,...)
- additional `WHERE` conditions, if any
- additional `JOIN`s, if any
- table structure ("40 fields" is something very different if they're all INTs or CHARs or TEXTs or VARCHARs or some combination).
- existing indexes
- read/write ratios on the table(s), and the related brouhaha (i.e. locking model used)
- and a gazillion other things

Try to run your query/queries with `EXPLAIN`; the query plan will give you much more specific data than we could ever provide.

Comment: +1 for EXPLAIN, it provides lots of useful information - though you'll probably want to read the docs to work out what it all means.

Comment: Where condition will be present 3-4 fields,other than this one more join will be preent,engine is myisam, almost 85% of the fields are varchar, each talbe is having only one primary key and no foreign keys

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you use a main table with only the **fixed** size fields. (No TEXT BLOB fields). Most of the time this should be enough. Then you only join the second table when you need those fields.

Accessing table with only fixed length fields is faster than using dynamic length rows.

An other good practice is to create an index with the most often used columns. If all the columns are in the index then MySQL can give you the result without accessing the table at all (by reading data only from the index).

You have to consider these options, but a real decision can only be made by knowing the ratio of operations you are performing on the database.

Comment: Aren't `TEXT` and `BLOB` fields stored separately, with only a (fixed-size) pointer stored in the table row proper?

Comment: @Piskvor I don't know of such a storage engine or `ROW_FORMAT` which does that, but I'm interested if you found some links.

Comment: @Piskvor It depends. The answer can be complicated. See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/ for InnoDB, MyISAM is different again.

Comment: @Isotopp: Hmm, that's more complicated than I thought. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Piskvor After reading this I still think it's a good idea to separate these long fields to a different table. Maybe even more so. :)

Comment: @vbence: Yes, yes it is; same with any variable type (such as `VARCHAR`). I was under the assumption that TEXT is effectively fixed-size, as far as the table row is concerned; it is apparently more complicated. Having a table with fixed-size rows is a Good Thing, definitely - sorry if I didn't make myself clear.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your query is complicated. It will be even more complicated if your tables contain fields that are being written to, if your data is cold or too large to be kept in memory. It is also dependent on the storage engine, storage engine version and a few other things.

Solid results you can get only by benchmarking.

I may contribute a useful anecdote, though. In another job, we had a user database that held all data for a single user in one row. User data was about 1-2K per user, in total, and we had 25 million user records.

The database has been reading and writing data in pages of 8K each (MySQL InnoDB would be 16K pages, btw). That means we have about 4-6 user records per database page, and about 5 million pages of data.

The user record contained fields that stored the time of the users last login. Between 7 and 9 in the morning we would see about 8 million unique users logging in, so we would be about 8 million pages being dirtied and in need of a writeback. Essentially we would be writing back the entire user table back to disk twice or thrice, each day.

We introduced an artificial 1:1 relationship which resembles your user and user_details pages: We had a user and a user_lastlogin table. The user_lastlogin records were very narrow, consisting essentially only of a user id and the (three different) last login times of a user (depending on service being used). Because user_lastlogin is very narrow we now have almost thousand records per page, and only 25.000 pages in the table. With 8 million unique logins, we now need to write back a lot less data (because checkpoints and page writebacks in a database are delayed). Disk I/O load sank by orders of magnitude.

Lesson learned: It can be very useful to separate static from volatile data (We considered the password static data, as we had about 15.000 password changes per day, whereas we had 8 million last_login updates per day).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put all data in one table. Else you are working against the DB normalisation rules. And why would you separate data about one user in 2 tables? Just restrict your SELECT results by not using wildcard selectorr as *, but makind a list with requested fields.

Comment: Efficiency or real-world requirements, perhaps? One table can be pseudonymous identifiers for systems' internal use, whereas the details table might be data that a) is needed comparatively less often (you don't need the user #19746's mailing address or star sign to see if he's allowed to access resource #0xdeadbeef; also, identifiers are usually integers, which are far faster to handle than VARCHARs or TEXTs - table width and composition has real impact on speed) or b) data that mustn't be accessible to all processes (HIPAA comes to mind).

Comment: I agree with that but this situation does not happend that often. I still prefer to keep everything in one table unless I will really see the benefit of separating data in more tables. He can use views if he wants to restrict viewable data for certain users or sections of the app. There are many user cases, I was speaking about the most common one, cause he did not mention any speficic requirements.

Comment: As for normalization, *that* will bite you as soon as your customer has a mailing address, a billing address, and a shipping address (most common example). The normalized approach there is definitely not "stuff them all into one row in the table".

Comment: I agree with that also :) but to recommend separating I need to see more info about the user data.

Comment: @Yasen Zhelev: Now we're in agreement :) That's why I objected to your unconditional "It is better to put all data in one table". Without knowledge of the specific data, we just don't know.

Comment: @Piskvor I made my mind because of that mainly "In my software most of the time i will be needing to join these two tables for producing outputs." With the info that the user gives I thought that this will be a good approach, but despite of that I agree with everything said by you. Especially the part with putting things like addresses in separate table. This one is a must!

Comment: my user table consists of mainly date fields and integers and 4 varchar fields, but the user details table is consisting 30 varchar fields and 2 text fields

Answer (score 0):

Joins are a relatively expensive operation, so if you can remove them that may speed things up. This comes at the cost of normalisation though.

Can you generate random user records via a script? If so you could just create 500,000 records using both schemas (all in one table and two tables with join) and see which is fastest. It might be that the difference is so small that there's no point in merging the tables.

Comment: With emphasis on "relatively". A 57-column table with 0.5M records will probably be anything but fast, esp. if strings are involved. "Join everything to everything" is indeed slow, but "removing joins speeds things up" is an overgeneralization. As you rightly note, it *may* or *may not*.

Comment: "This comes at the cost of normalisation though." It comes at the cost of artificial id numbers. Storing a natural key instead of an artificial id number can eliminate a join without affecting normalization at all. That may or may not speed things up, though.